# Python BeautifulSoup parsing

Tags: python, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some content (am very new to Python) and I have hit a stumbling block. The code I am trying to scrape is:

```
<h2><a href="/best-sellers/sj-b9822.html">Spear & Jackson Predator Universal Hardpoint Saw     - 22"</a></h2>
<p><span class="productlist_mostwanted_rrp">    
Was: <span class="strikethrough">£12.52</span></span><span class="productlist_mostwanted_save">Save: £6.57(52%)</span></p>

<div class="clear"></div>

<p class="productlist_mostwanted_price">Now: £5.95</p>
```

What I am trying to scrape is the link text (Spear & Jackson etc) and the price (£5.95). I have looked about on Google, the BeautifulSoup documentation and on this forum and I managed to get to extract the "Now: £5.95" using this code:

```
for node in soup.findAll('p', { "class" : "productlist_grid_price" }):
     print ''.join(node.findAll(text=True))
```

However the result I am after is just 5.95. I have also had limited success trying to get the link text (Spear & Jackson) using:

```
soup.h2.a.contents[0]
```

However of course this returns just the first result.

The ultimate result that I am aiming for is to have the results look like:

```
Spear & Jackson Predator Universal Hardpoint Saw - 22 5.95
etc
etc
```

As I am looking to export this to a csv, I need to figure out how to put the data into 2 columns. Like I say I am very new to python so I hope this makes sense.

I appreciate any help!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('prueba.html').read())
item = re.sub('\s+', ' ', soup.h2.a.text)
price = soup.find('p', {'class': 'productlist_mostwanted_price'}).text
price = re.search('\d+\.\d+', price).group(0)

print item, price
```

Example output:

> Spear & Jackson Predator Universal Hardpoint Saw - 22" 5.95

Note that for the item, the regular expression is used just to remove extra whitespace, while for the price is used to capture the number.

Comment: Thanks! That grabs the first one. Would you mind informing me how I might construct a loop in order to return all the results, as this code returns just the first, albeit perfectly.

Comment: That depends on their location in the DOM (if they are in the same page).

Comment: Yes they are in the same page. I have tried creating a loop but my efforts are only worthy of scorn. Still quite new to programming in general!

Comment: Can anyone help me loop this so it returns all of the results rather than the first one? Thanks

Comment: As I said, they depend on theri location on the DOM. Please provide missing information or just ask a new question as a follow up of this one.

Comment: As I said before, they are on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '''
<h2><a href="/best-sellers/sj-b9822.html">Spear & Jackson Predator Universal Hardpoint Saw     - 22</a></h2>
<p><span class="productlist_mostwanted_rrp">    
Was: <span class="strikethrough">&pound;12.52</span></span><span class="productlist_mostwanted_save">Save: &pound;6.57(52%)</span></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p class="productlist_mostwanted_price">Now: &pound;5.95</p>
'''

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
desc = soup.h2.a.getText()
price_str = soup.find('p', {"class": "productlist_mostwanted_price" }).getText()
price = float(re.search(r'[0-9.]+', price_str).group())

print desc, price
```

Comment: Thanks however it shoes the price incorrecty (says 5.0) and doesn't loop through. Thanks though

Comment: @PeterStannett Really?  Running it through Python2.7 gives ``Spear & Jackson Predator Universal Hardpoint Saw     - 22 5.95``.   Did you have a cut-and-paste issue?

Comment: The problem was completely entirely me. Apologies! I re-ran it as copy and paste rather than me typing it out and it was fine! Would the [0-9] mean if a product was say £16 it wouldn't print? Also I am struggling to get the code to do more than one. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Can anyone help me try and construct a loop in order to return all the results in a page? I have tried but am struggling to get it to work! Thanks.